# designing an api - interdependent parameter

Tags: json, rest

i am trying to design a rest api.

a few of the parameters are interdependent.

so I have the following structure that I return when someone makes the /account api call

```
"money": {
     "name": "alpha",
     "data": {
         "total": 30"
     }
```

}

problem is that what goes into the "data" object depends on the "name".

So if name = alpha, you get the following json back

```
"money": {
     "name": "alpha",
     "data": {
         "total": 30"
     }
```

}

if name = bravo, you get the following json back from us

```
"money": {
     "name": "bravo",
     "data": {
         "threshold": 30"
     }
```

}

every month, "name" parameter changes for the account. Last month it was "alpha" because the account was on the "alpha" plan. This month it is "bravo" because the account is on the "bravo" plan.

How do you correctly design an api with interdependent result parameters in rest?

Answer (score 0):

In your documentation to your API you just mention that the format is the following:

```
"money": {
     "name": "alpha",
     "data": {
         "total": 30,
         "threshold": 30
     }
}
```

Where total and threshold are optional and if name == "alpha" then total is present, if name == "bravo" then threshold is present.